# Trailhead login issue and security question

Tags: security, trailhead, login-errors

i am facing an issue. i was practicing something so i made a trailhead account. after timeout logout, i didnt know the password. when i click forgot password i received an email. after clicking that link there was a security question about **which city you were born?** , i never saved any city at all.
now please guide me that is there any other way to login? how can i reset now where i dont know the answer?

Comment: I suggest you go through [Global Support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321274&type=1&mode=1) for this.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  i have found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found a solution. i logged into trailhead account from there i opened my **hands on orgs** from there i launched my salesforce practice account.

[image]

then i also reset my password successfully as mentioned in image below.

[image]